# convert a base64 data into an image file, rename it and move it to a specified location

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to convery a base64 data into an image file and then rename it and store it to a specified location, below is my codes

```
//the first image to be saved, first, we get the extension
$extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
//second we rename the file
$fileName = rand(11111,99999).'_'.$request->id;
//and then move the file to a specified location with the new name
$request->file('image')->move(base_path().'/public/images/uploads/', $fileName.'.'.$extension);
//second image, this one is on a base64 format so first we decode it
$image = base64_decode($request->thumbnail);
//and then store it to the same location of the first image with its new name and extension same to the first image
$image->move(base_path().'/public/images/uploads/', $fileName.'_thumbnail.'.$extension);
```

Please read the comment line per code line from the codes above, anyway, it throws me an error

> Call to a member function move() on a non-object
>   and its pointing in this line

```
$image->move(base_path().'/public/images/uploads/', $fileName.'_thumbnail.'.$extension);
```

any help, clues, ideas, suggestions, recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using this function to convert base64string(data) to image and rename...

```
public function image_upload($filename, $uploadedfile) 
{
    $save_file_path = "/var/www/html/uploads/";
    $save_file_path .= $filename;
    $image_file = base64_decode($uploadedfile);

    //DELETES EXISTING
    if (file_exists($save_file_path)) 
        unlink($save_file_path);

    //CREATE NEW FILE
    file_put_contents($save_file_path, $image_file); 

    //DOUBLE CHECK FILE IF EXIST 
    return ((file_exists($save_file_path)) ? true : false );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause `base64_decode` is just returning a string you have to do this.

```
file_put_contents(base_path().'/public/images/uploads/' . $fileName.'_thumbnail.'.$extension, $image)
```

It just saves the image in the location `base_path().'/public/images/uploads/', $fileName.'_thumbnail.'.$extension`.

The error `call to a member function on a non-object` always occurs, when you are trying to call a method on a non object like string, int, ...

Comment: and then I have this error "file_put_contents() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given"

Comment: @CodeDemon sry there was a `,` instead of a `.` Now it should work!

Comment: yes it did store, but why seems the stored image is broken, like if you click on it, there's no preview?

Answer (score 0):

`base64_decode()` returns a string as confirmed from the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php). You are trying to access the method `move()` on a string, which is not an object and does not have any methods on it.

You now have the contents of the image decoded, so you will be able to call `file_put_contents(base_path().'/public/images/uploads/'.$fileName.'_thumbnail.'.$extension, $image);` which will write the decoded contents to the specified file.

Comment: and then I receive this error "file_put_contents() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given"

Comment: there was a stray comma which I have fixed.